# JAXB: How to generate English Javadoc

Tags: java, jaxb, xjc, maven-jaxb2-plugin

When I generate JAXB classes using the [maven-jaxb2-plugin](https://java.net/projects/maven-jaxb2-plugin/pages/Home) I get classes with partial(!?) German Javadoc. (My default locale: de_CH)

What I want: English Javadoc

I tried to set the maven opts: `-Duser.language=en -Duser.country=US`
but it had no effect.

How can I generate JAXB classes with English Javadoc?

Here is the Javadoc for some JAXB classes with partial German Javadoc: http://drombler.sourceforge.net/DromblerACP/docs/site/0.2.1-SNAPSHOT/apidocs/org/drombler/acp/core/action/jaxb/package-frame.html

Here is the according XSD: http://sourceforge.net/p/drombler/drombler-acp/ci/default/tree/drombler-acp-core-action/src/main/resources/actions.xsd

Here is the according POM: http://sourceforge.net/p/drombler/drombler-acp/ci/default/tree/drombler-acp-core-action/pom.xml

**Related JAXB Issue:**

https://java.net/jira/browse/JAXB-1001

Any workaround?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can pass arbitrary properties to XJC using the `args/arg` element in the configuration of the `maven-jaxb2-plugin`:

```
<configuration>
    <extension>true</extension>
    <args>
        <arg>-Duser.language=en</arg>
    </args>
</configuration>
```

These arguments will be just passed to XJC.

However I have no idea if `-Duser.language=en` `-Duser.country=US` are the right options. Anyway the `args/arg` will be passed to XJC. If it does not work please file an issue [here](https://java.net/jira/browse/MAVEN_JAXB2_PLUGIN).

Disclaimer: I'm the author of maven-jaxb2-plugin.

**Update**

This feature is implemented in the version `0.10.0`. Now you can do [the following](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/blob/master/tests/MAVEN_JAXB2_PLUGIN-87/pom.xml#L28):

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <locale>es</locale>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately it did not work. (unknown parameter -Duser.language=en). I file an issue here: https://java.net/jira/browse/MAVEN_JAXB2_PLUGIN-87

Comment: As this is answer is from the author of the maven-jaxb2-plugin and thus likely to be the best answer there is, I accept it.

Comment: Thank you for the report, I'll be looking into it.

Comment: @Puce Please see the update. This feature is implemented now.

Comment: Great, thanks, I will try it out once version 0.10.0 is available.

Comment: @Puce 0.10.0 is released now: https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/releases/tag/0.10.0

Answer (score 5):

in windows command line:

```
> SET JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Duser.language=en -Duser.country=US -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
> xjc .
```

tested with jdk9

Answer (score 0):

This bug seems to be a regression as the issue does not exist in the previous versions.

So maybe you could use `org.codehaus.mojo:jaxb2-maven-plugin:1.5`...

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.5</version>
</plugin>
```

Note: in the 1.5, multi-executions did not work (see [jaxb2-maven-plugin only executing first execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22608289/jaxb2-maven-plugin-only-executing-first-execution)). I don't know if they will ever get their plug-in right.

Answer (score 0):

I needed this as well....the only reasonable workaround (for other plugins like the mojohaus/jaxb2-maven-plugin) is to invoking Locale.setDefault(YOURLANGUAGE) before the generation of the files (in my case generation of java files from xsd with xjc)...

You could for example use the maven antrun plugin to set the default locale before the execution of the generation:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>setLocaleFixedToUS</id>
            <phase>initialize</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <target>
            <scriptdef name="setLocaleFixedToUS" language="javascript">
                <![CDATA[
                    importClass(java.util.Locale);
                    actualDefault = Locale.getDefault();
                    project.setProperty("actual-default-locale", actualDefault);
                    Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);
                ]]>
            </scriptdef>
            <setLocaleFixedToUS />
        </target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

All other solutions with setting -Duser.language=en -Duser.country=US or commandline arguments didn't work for me either.

Comment: Have a look at the accepted answer. Since version 0.10.0 it works.